# Use .net core project with moniker net451 in classic class library

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net5

Why I'm not able to use class library targeting to **.net core** with moniker **net451** in classic .net class library (.net framework 4.5.1)?

Edit:
When I try add reference in Class library project for .net framework 4.5.1 (full 451 for next time) to .net core project following error showed up.
[image]

Here is config.json from .net core project Idea7.Entity:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Idea7.Entity Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Sebastian Bušek" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": { }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give more details about what happens? How does your project look like? What error do you get?

Comment: Changed the tags, as this discussion was about RC1. Users should now upgrade to RC2, http://dot.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, it's not possible to reference **.net core** class library in **.net framework 4.5.1** class library project in Visual Studio by click "Add reference"; but you can add reference to builded *.dll.

To do that, you need to do few simple steps:

- Check Produce outputs on build in project properties (Build menu item)
- In solution directory is "artifacts" folder and it contains all builded .net core class libraris

Little bit flaffy, but working...

Comment: Another way is to publish the .NET Core class library as NuGet package and then consume it in the .NET Framework projects.